# How to Mock File upload in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mockery

I am using a 3rd party API to manage my uploaded images, I have abstracted this API with my own class, and also written class to test file upload, but the files get uploaded to the web every time I run the test, I will like to prevent this and use mock to test that the upload function is being called instead.

How do I go about this?

Comment: you can do one thing : write a function file_upload in php and it will accept url of uploaded files, in this function you call your 3rd party upload image function, that function will return you true/false of file success/fail

Comment: @Monty I have a function that does that for me already

Comment: where you getting problem. explain more, not getting you clearly

Comment: Sharing relevant code snippets might help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do.

I create a UploadedFile isntance (mock a uploaded file) and pass this to my Service Class - This is my approach for testing my Service Class that handles file uploads.

If you want to test the Controller method, I suggest you go with a Acceptance Test and use a real browser to send the request. I could'nt find a decent way of doing this.

```
//Mock a uploaded file
  $uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(codecept_data_dir().'/attachments/temporary/' . $filename, $filename, $mimeType, $size);
```

You will need to `use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;` on top.